# Android app - retrieving messages from Gmail

Tags: java, android, email, gmail-api

I'm a beginner learning android app development.

I have a requirement for a user to be able to Read messages (just the body content - text only) from a Gmail account (Read-only mail extraction?) and save the email content within the app.

I don't need to retrieve messages when the user is not actively using the app.

The app and SQLite database I am building sits on the phones internal local storage. I do not have a backend server.

I have looked at the Gmail API tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/

As I understand, I need to use the Gmail API and ensure that a user of my app can authenticate as a Gmail user.

Is anyone able to advise:

1) if this is feasible to do without a back end server? 
2) any tutorials as to how to approach this, or would you recommend just working through the material I listed above?
3) (I understand this is highly subjective) how substantial a task this is to undertake for a learner (This is an educational project, so I am limited by time - if it takes me more than 3-4 days I will run out of time!) An idea as to how long it might take someone who is experienced would help me to grasp the scale of the task.

Comment: I will answer the last question of yours. Yes it will take more than 3-4 days. And based on your earlier statement that you are a learner. I would suggest looking up for a different start project

Comment: Ah thanks @MDMalik - this is exactly the info I needed, but was a bit scared to ask because it is so subjective! How long do you think it would take? (For someone experienced, and for a learner?)

Answer (score 0):

Google uses [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authenticate and track applications connected with a user's account. You will need to get a security key for app from google. Because you do not have server, you will want to get a client only key and not the service key. You can get the client key by going to the Google API Console. For help about how to let the user sign-in to their account you can look at this Android tutorials [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). After you get the google sign-in working you can continue on to getting the Gmail messages.

It may seem like a complicated process, but you should be able to have in working in a short amount of time if you go through the tutorials on Google's developer's site. I got a similar app working in only about an hour. To add a nice user interface will take longer, but thats up to you.